# Cant fix the problem "java: illegal start of expression"

Tags: java, function, compiler-errors, syntax-error, expression

I'm new to Java and trying to learn it, but I always get this error "java: illegal start of expression" in my code and I don't know why. Maybe one of you can help me its on line 36, `public static void printBoard(int[] meinBoard)`.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int turn=0;
        String winner = null;
        int[] board = new int[9];
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            board[i] = -1;
        }
        while(winner == null){
            winner = "Player1";
        }

        printBoard(board);
    }

    /**

     *  # | # | #
     * __________
     *  # | # | #
     * ----------
     *  # | # | #
     */


    public static void checkWinner(int[] board) {
        int winner = -1;
        if (board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2] && board[0] != -1) {
            winner = board[0];
        } else if (board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5] && board[0] != -1) {
            winner = board[0];
        }

 public static void printBoard(int[] meinBoard) {
            System.out.println(meinBoard[0] + " | " + meinBoard[1] + " | " + meinBoard[2]);
            System.out.println("_________");
            System.out.println(meinBoard[3] + " | " + meinBoard[4] + " | " + meinBoard[5]);
            System.out.println("_________");
            System.out.println(meinBoard[6] + " | " + meinBoard[7] + " | " + meinBoard[8]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `checkWinner` function is missing a closing brace.

Comment: The "Illegal Start of Expression" exception means that you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close the method checkWinner:

```
public static void checkWinner(int[] board) {
    int winner = -1;
    if (board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2] && board[0] != -1) {
        winner = board[0];
    } else if (board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5] && board[0] != -1) {
        winner = board[0];
    }
} //<- add this
```

I recommend that you use a convenient IDE to mark you with non-closed methods, or to fix you with minor code issues